# optimize a 'having count (distinct ) ' query for big data

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I have below query that I need to run on a table with 100million records but it's extremellyyy slow (been running for 5 hours so far)
I am not sure how to optimize it , would be grateful for any help
The table has an index on DID and week_no, and contains several other columns not indexed, and a primary key (id) indexed

```
 DELETE FROM test WHERE "DID" IN (SELECT "DID" FROM test GROUP BY "DID" having count(distinct week_no) < 4 );
```

thanks!

Comment: Is it MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

This would be most efficiently written using a `DELETE` with `JOIN` (or `USING` for PostgreSQL) to avoid having to compute the counts for each row:

For PostgreSQL:

```
DELETE
FROM test t1
USING (SELECT did, COUNT(DISTINCT week_no) AS num_weeks
       FROM test
       GROUP BY did) t2
WHERE t2.did = t1.did AND num_weeks < 4
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2cada30ceb5de82e93f18200e8f87f61)

In MySQL:

```
DELETE t1
FROM test t1
JOIN (SELECT did, COUNT(DISTINCT week_no) AS num_weeks
      FROM test
      GROUP BY did) t2 ON t2.did = t1.did
WHERE num_weeks < 4
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f1d6a35304c5dd6416071892c7e483b5)